# Producer for injecting HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, cdi

As I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69101304/why-is-httpservletrequest-injectable-via-cdi-but-httpservletresponse-isnt) and tried myself, it is not possible to inject the `HttpServletResponse` of the current `@RequestScoped`.

So it seems that you have to implement a custom CDI `Procuder` or `@Produces` method to be able to inject the `HttpserlvetResponse`. I have two questions:

1. Where would one implement this producer? Maybe with a web filter that sets the response in a `@RequestScoped` bean?
2. Is injecting the response even a good idea in the first place since there is no way to inject the response by default?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I just found the [Servlet module from Apache DeltaSpike](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/servlet.html) which allows for injectable servlet objects such as the `HttpServletResponse`. So there is no need for a custom CDI `Producer` or `@Produces` method.